# Couldn't add back button to action bar after hours of searching for solution

Tags: android, android-layout, back-button

After searching for hours to find the solution for errors in my code, I end up asking a question here.. Ive tried every solutions offered but still couldn't get it right. Maybe there's something wrong in my codes.

So these are my codes:

AboutUsActivity.java:

```
    public class AboutUsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
        case android.R.id.home:
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_about_us);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


  }
 }
```

My AndroidManifest file:

```
 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".activity.LoginActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".activity.GeneralSettingActivity" android:parentActivityName=".activity.ProfileActivity"/>
    <activity android:name=".activity.RegisterActivity" android:parentActivityName=".activity.LoginActivity"/>
    <activity android:name=".activity.ResetPasswordActivity" android:parentActivityName=".activity.LoginActivity"/>
    <activity android:name=".activity.HomeActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".activity.AboutUsActivity"
        android:parentActivityName=".activity.HomeActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.ActionBar"
        />
    <activity android:name=".activity.ApplyTutor" android:parentActivityName=".activity.HomeActivity"/>
    <activity android:name=".activity.PrivacyPolicyActivity" android:parentActivityName=".activity.HomeActivity"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.ProfileActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_profile"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity android:name=".activity.EditProfileActivity" android:parentActivityName=".activity.ProfileActivity"/>
    <activity android:name=".activity.EarningActivity" android:parentActivityName=".activity.ProfileActivity"/>
    <activity android:name=".activity.ScheduleActivity" android:parentActivityName=".activity.ProfileActivity"/>
    <activity android:name=".activity.RatingReviewActivity" android:parentActivityName=".activity.ProfileActivity"/>
    <activity android:name=".activity.RequestActivity"></activity>
</application>
```

My styles.xml:

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>

</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>

</style>

<style name="AppTheme.ActionBar"/>


<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

my activity_about_us.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.cqaai.tutorpal.activity.AboutUsActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="Page name: About Us"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Android Monitor display error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference
                                                                            at com.example.cqaai.tutorpal.activity.AboutUsActivity.onCreate(AboutUsActivity.java:32)
```

Comment: Do you mean a navigation icon when clicked to go to another activity?

Comment: <style name="AppTheme.ActionBar"/> 
 Should have parent and that too with action bar. Otherwise use toolbar

Comment: Do you see back arrow but it doesn't work? Or you don't see any back arrow?

Comment: @Xenolion nope, just the back button to go to previous/parent activity

Comment: @Mehmed the getSupportActionBar gives me null. Sorry i forgot to include error message. Will edit it shortly

Comment: @Mehmed i have added error message

Answer (score 1):

Edit your Activity to include these two override methods:

```
public class AboutUsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_about_us);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


  }
 }


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.about_us_activity, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
switch (item.getItemId()) {
    // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
    case android.R.id.home:
        NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
        return true;
}
return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

And make a new Android Resource Directory in your res folder by right clicking the res folder in your project structure and choose Resource Type: menu. Then create a new menu resource file and write the following code in there:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<!-- other possible items -->

</menu>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` as base application theme and that's why `getSupportActionBar()` returns null. That theme has no action bar as its name suggests. There are two solutions.

***First Solution:*** You can change your theme to a theme with action bar, like `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar`.

***Second Solution:*** You can continue with `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` but you have to use Toolbar. For this, you need to update your layout as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.cqaai.tutorpal.activity.AboutUsActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Page name: About Us"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

...and your `AboutUsActivity`'s `onCreate()` as follows:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_about_us);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}
```

I hope it works now.

Comment: Hi when i add toolbar in AboutUsActivity.java it gives me an error:         (android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar)
in AppCompatActivity cannot be applied
to
(android.widget.Toolbar

Comment: nvm ,It works now! thank you, the error just know is because ive import wrong toolbar.